# How to switch on generic-type-parameter in F#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, f#, functional-programming

I have the following C# code:

```
public static T Attr<T>(this XElement x, string name)
    {
        var attr = x.Attribute(name);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            return (T)(object)(attr == null ? 0 : int.Parse(attr.Value));

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
            return (T)(object)(attr == null ? 0 : float.Parse(attr.Value));
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
            return (T)(object)(attr == null ? "" : attr.Value);
        return (T)(object)null;
    }
```

I've been trying for an hour or so to translate this into F# but haven't had any success, and keep getting error messages like "type int has no subtype..." which have me completely befuddled. My exploration of the bestiary of `:?` `:?>` and other operators haven't given me any success.

How would I go about re-writing this in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the same logic, you could use if/else's just like C#, or define a map of types to "type converters." But I would probably opt for something simpler, like this:

```ml
type XElement with
  member this.Attr<'T>(name) = 
    match this.Attribute(XName.Get name) with
    | null -> Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
    | attr -> Convert.ChangeType(attr.Value, typeof<'T>) :?> 'T
```

Comment: ChangeType is giving me a "takes 3 arguments but was given 2" error for this code; it seems to me that it's not picking the right overload when i do this in F#, even though it works great in C#. Any idea how I can force that particular overload of the method?

Comment: What version of .NET? This compiles on 4.5.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 Portable Subset (i.e. it's in a PCL). It turns out that the Silverlight 4 profile is missing that overload of `Convert.ChangeType`, and only has the version with an `IFormatProvider`. I'm stuck with the Silverlight-compliant PCL target until F# 3.1 becomes available for VS 2012, which should be soon, but can you think of any nice way to work around it in the mean time?

Comment: Pass `null` for the `IFormatProvider` and it will use the current culture.